# Custom cell component with input not re-rendering on search filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently implementing a data table using Vue.js 2 and [Vue Data Table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@andresouzaabreu/vue-data-table), including a search filter and custom cell components with input fields.

When filtering the data using the search filter, the input fields' bound values, using `v-model`, won't re-render. Data entries are removed, but the bound values stay the same.

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue3-data-table-demo-forked-w24j4z) to show what I mean:

Notice that when filtering via search, the values of the input fields in column 3 don't update or re-render. The first entry has a job of 'Recreational Therapist', but when filtering for 'Corine', which is the second entry, it still has the value of 'Recreational Therapist'.

Is this an issue of the Vue Data Table library, or am I doing something wrong regarding Vue.